# Clear console and info panes with scripting

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a simple script that will clear the [`Info Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info_editor.html) and the [`Python Console`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html). As seen in the areas marked by green and orange rectangles receptively.

[image: Blender console and info windows]

It's straight forward without a script:

In the *Info Editor* <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Delete*.
And in the *Python Console* <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Clear All*.

Code-wise, I've tried this:

```
bpy.ops.info.select_all(action="SELECT")
bpy.ops.info.report_delete()

bpy.ops.console.clear(scrollback=True, history=False)
```

...but the error says that the context is incorrect.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script to clear the *Python Console* and the *Info Panel*. Unfortunately you cannot clear the last *Info Panel* log entry `bpy.ops.text.run_script()` because it is logged after the script completes. Also note that you have three (3) options to clear the *Python Console* using `bpy.ops.console.clear`. I have left a comment beside each line so you will just have to comment out the lines you don't need.

```
import bpy

# ========================================================================================
#
# Starting in 3.2 context overrides are deprecated in favor of temp_override
# https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override
#
# They are scheduled to be removed in 3.3
#
# ========================================================================================

def use_temp_override():
    ''' Determine whether Blender is 3.2 or newer and requires
        the temp_override function, or is older and requires
        the context override dictionary
    '''
    version = bpy.app.version
    major = version[0]
    minor = version[1]

    return not (major < 3 or (major == 3 and minor < 2))

def get_areas(type):
    return [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == type]

def get_regions(areas):
    return [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

# ========================================================================================
# execute script using temp override
# ========================================================================================

win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen

if use_temp_override():

    areas  = get_areas('CONSOLE')

    with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, area=areas[0], regions=get_regions(areas)[0], screen=scr):
        bpy.ops.console.clear(history=True) # clear command history and scrollback history
        bpy.ops.console.clear(scrollback=False, history=True) # clear command history only
        bpy.ops.console.clear() # clear scrollback history only

    areas  = get_areas('INFO')

    with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, area=areas[0], regions=get_regions(areas)[0], screen=scr):
        bpy.ops.info.select_all(action="SELECT")
        bpy.ops.info.report_delete()
        
# ========================================================================================
# execute script using legacy override
# ========================================================================================        

else:
    areas  = get_areas('CONSOLE')

    override = {
        'window': win,
        'screen': scr,
        'area': areas[0],
        'region': get_regions(areas)[0],
    }
    bpy.ops.console.clear(override, history=True) # clear command history and scrollback history
    bpy.ops.console.clear(override) # clear scrollback history only
    bpy.ops.console.clear(override, scrollback=False, history=True) # clear command history only

    areas  = get_areas('INFO')

    override['area'] = areas[0]
    override['region'] = get_regions(areas)[0]

    bpy.ops.info.select_all(override, action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.info.report_delete(override)
```